# Javaの文字列の中でRubyのような式の展開ってできますか？

Tags: ruby, java

Javaの文字列の中で以下のRubyのコードのように式の展開をすることは可能でしょうか？

```
name = "Joel Spolsky"
p "Hello #{name}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 標準ライブラリにはないです。あえて一番近いのといえば、 [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) ですね。

```
String name = "Joel Spolsky"
String result = String.format("Hello %s", name);
```

あとは、テンプレートライブラリを使う話になってくると思います。Java にはたくさんあると思うので、
どれを選ぶかは、人それぞれでしょう。

ちょっと冗長ですが、例えば Mushtache ([Handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java))　はどうでしょう。

```
String name = "Joel Spolsky"
Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
Template template = handlebars.compileInline("Hello {{name}}");
System.out.println(template.apply(name));
```

Answer (score 4):

Java言語では残念ながら不可能です。

例えばApache Commonsの[`StrSubstitutor`クラス](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html)で似たような処理を実現可能です。（変数名から直接マッピングはできません）

```
Map m = new HashMap();
m.put("name", "Joel Spolsky");
System.out.println((new StrSubstitutor(m)).replace("Hello ${name}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

すでに回答されているように、Java 標準ライブラリでは不可能です。

ちょっとした式展開がしたいだけで、テンプレートライブラリを使うほどでも…という場合は、正規表現を使った変換を自前で行ってもいいかもしれません。

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TemplateTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", "Joel Spolsky");
    StringBuilder tmpl = new StringBuilder("Hello #{name}");
    System.out.println(replace(tmpl, map));
  }
  private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\#\\{([^\\#\\{\\}]*)\\}");
  private static String replace(StringBuilder tmpl, Map<String, String> map) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(tmpl);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tmpl.length() && m.find(i)) {
      String key = m.group(1);
      String val = Objects.toString(map.get(key), "null");
      tmpl.replace(m.start(), m.end(), val);
      i = m.start() + val.length();
      m = pattern.matcher(tmpl);
    }
    return tmpl.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

すでにご存知とは思いますが、Java標準の範囲内で最も一般的な代用法は `+` でつないでゆくことです。

```
String name = "Joel Spolsky";
System.out.println("Hello " + name);
```

Rubyと違って、+で挟まれた式は[文字列以外なら文字列に変換される](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) ([日本語訳](http://www.y-adagio.com/public/standards/tr_javalang2/expressions.doc.html#39990)) ので、計算式なども問題なく文字列の間に挟むことができます(文字列の`+`と数値の`+`をコンパイラが混同するので、計算式はカッコで囲むように気をつけてください)。

```
String name = "Joel Spolsky";
int birthyear = 1965;
System.out.println("Happy new year " + name + " and your age is " + (2015 - birthyear));
```

ただ、`+`はメモリ効率が悪いため、デバッグプリント以外には向いていません。

性能が必要な場合は [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) が使われます。こちらも標準ライブラリで、`import`は必要ありません。

```
String name = "Joel Spolsky";
int birthyear = 1965;
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
message.append("Happy new year ").append(name).append(" and your age is ").append(2015 - birthyear);
System.out.println(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

java から ruby の機能をつかいたいなら、jruby を使うという方法も考えられます。

```
// See http://www29.atwiki.jp/red5server/pages/37.html                                                                  
//     http://dior.ics.muni.cz/~makub/ruby/                                                                             
// 1. put jaruy.jar を カレントフォルダに置く.                                                                          
// 2. $ javac -cp ./jruby.jar App.java                                                                                  
// 3. $ java -cp .:./jruby,jara App                                                                                     
//    time=2015-01-03 20:45:46 +0900                                                                                    

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws ScriptException {
        new App();
    }

    public App() throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine jruby = new  ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");

        String script = "$myval = \"time=#{Time.now}\"";
        jruby.eval(script);
        String myval = (String) jruby.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).get("myval");
        System.out.println("myval=" + myval);
    }
}
```

これを compile, 実行すると stdout に次の様な文字列が出力されます。
  (java 1.8.0_05, jruby 1.7.18 on MacOSX 10.10.1 で実行)

```
time=2015-01-03 20:45:46 +0900
```